# Removing an Entity from Dynamics CRM 2013's Navigation Bar

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Can someone please tell me how I can remove an entity from the Navigation bar in Dynamics CRM 2013? I want to remove the Contracts (seen on the left below)

[image: Nav Bar in Dynamics CRM 2013]

I find my way to the entity, but the tick box is disabled for me, so I can't make it hide under services!

[image: Disabled Tick box for CRM Entity]

Answer (score 2):

Contracts is a built-in entity and for this reason the checkbox is disabled.

If you want only to remove the entity from the navigation bar (meaning that the users will still have the privileges to create contracts and search them with advanced find) try with the SiteMap Editor included inside XrmToolbox

http://xrmtoolbox.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks @GuidoPreite. How can I find out the [following details](http://i61.tinypic.com/adjar4.png) when wanting to connect XRMToolbox? All I know is the URL to access the CRM!

Comment: Are you using CRM Online? Or on-premises? Depending on the answer tick the right boxes. If you are not sure if you are using IFD for on-premises, ask your administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all privileges to the Contract entity from all Security Roles. Administrators will still see it but everyone else will not.

If you don't want admins to see it, then use SiteMapEditor as answered by Guido.

Oh, by the way, to edit the privileges to an entity across all roles, you can use another of the tools in XrmToolbox!